# What does this std::upper bound exactly do in this code?

Tags: c++

[Grade School - Excercism](https://exercism.io/tracks/cpp/exercises/grade-school/solutions/b2708095bc0b48c8a3c175768150c280)

There is a test suite attached to the exercise as well.

```
void school::add(std::string name, int grade)
{
    roster_[grade].insert(std::upper_bound(roster_[grade].begin(), roster_[grade].end(), name), name);
}
```

---

roster_ is defined as `std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> roster_;`.

Comment: Have you look up what `upper_bound` does?  What about it is causing you to not know what it is doing?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound

Comment: What do you mean comparison with name inside the function? It's comparing the values in rooster_ to name.

Comment: I was a bit confused on how that worked but the explanations below sorted it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I find this definition easier to remember/visualize:

- `it = std::upper_bound(beg, end, x)` gives you the `it`erator to the *last* position where you can insert `x` in the container `[beg, end)` such that the container remains sorted if it is sorted;
- `it = std::lower_bound(beg, end, x)` gives you the `it`erator to the *first* position where you can insert `x` in the container `[beg, end)` such that the container remains sorted if it is sorted.

Therefore, given `std::vector<int> v{0,2,2,2,3};`,

- `std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 2)` returns the iterator to the `3`, because inserting `2` just before the `3` doesn't break the sorting;
- `std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 1)` returns the iterator to the first `2` because inserting `1` just before it doesn't break the sorting.

Therefore, that code (adding some new line for clarity) inserts `name` at the last place it can go without breaking a pre-existing sorting.

```cpp
roster_[grade].insert(
    std::upper_bound(roster_[grade].begin(), roster_[grade].end(), name),
    name);
```

The definitions you find on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) are useful and necessary if you assume the container is *not* sorted, in which case these functions are still useful, but it in a less obvious way, imho.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful :)

Comment: @fazfactor, good reason for accepting it, no? :P

Answer (score 1):

Your code inserts name into a sorted list in the correct place. You've got:

```cpp
roster_[grade].insert(
    std::upper_bound(roster_[grade].begin(), roster_[grade].end(), name),
    name);
```

where `rooster_[grade]` is a std::vector. What happens is:

1. you use std::upper_bound to find the first item in the list that is larger than name, i.e. the item that name should be inserted before in order to keep the list sorted. This relies on your list already being sorted, and probably uses a binary search. If it doesn't find any larger values, i.e. name is larger than all values in the list, it'll return the end iterator.
2. you use std::vector::insert with the return value from std::upper_bound to insert name at that position. If we have the end iterator we'll append name to the end of the list.